# Should the user who asked the question get rep for good answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions

I just upvoted an answer that helped me solve the problem.   I was just about to close the page when I realized that I should probably upvote the question which inspired the answer.  This led to the thought that "maybe this should be automatic."

If someone asks a question that inspires a very good answer that helps a lot of people, should they get some of the credit.  (say 1 point for every up vote on the highest rated answer to the question.)

The goal, of course, would be to motivate people to ask questions that generated the best answers.

Comment: No. This would lead to people posting crap questions but still get reputation points from upvotes of answers. It is not a problem on most sites, but it worsens the current situation on SO.

Comment: +1 for inspiring nicael's great answer.

Comment: @Servy +1 for rolling me over 1,000 week rep :D

Answer (score 6):

> The goal, of course, would be to motivate people to ask questions that generated the best answers.

Are you sure that the best answers will be inspired only by the best questions? I don't think so and suggest you to check the [Reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal) gold badge - do you think the questions users answered to get Reversal are good?

Also there are [another](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/228280/good-answers-to-bad-questions-that-dont-qualify-for-the-reversal-badge) 2000 good answers to 2000 bad questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are many, oft bemoaned, examples across the entire network of poor questions that have somehow inspired great answers.  The blog post [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) goes into this a bit.

> Consider the question Does torture work well as an interrogation technique? on Skeptics. Is this a brilliant question? Is it even an original question? No, it’s just a mundane grain of sand question that could have been asked by anyone at any time. What makes it remarkable is the incredible answer on that question by Larian LeQuella with over 100 upvotes.

The [sound of coins dropping](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/can-i-compute-the-mass-of-a-coin-based-on-the-sound-of-its-fall) on physics had two associated meta posts... one of which [Mass of a coin question went viral, despite inital downvotes and negative comments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/mass-of-a-coin-question-went-viral-despite-inital-downvotes-and-negative-commen) has the bit:

> I'm going to echo one of John Rennie's points, but more forcefully. Really it is not a great question. It hit upon a great topic, and allowed for some really great answers, but the question itself does no prior research, nor does it give any indication about what direction the answers should take.
>
> It's phrased like the questions at the top of xkcd: What If posts, but keep in mind the author there plenty of options and only deals with the questions that lead to the most amusing discussion. There is already filtering going on. Because all questions posted here first before downvotes and closevotes, our filtering process is more transparent, but that doesn't mean we're doing any more filtering than any other quality site.

Its not a great question.  It gets all the reward it should (and some people will argue too much) by its visibility from the great answers.